# How acceptor can add value to state and send back to initiator

Tags: kotlin, corda

I have scenario:

1. NodeA sends state to NodeB (State: value=100, CustomerFlag=**0**)
2. NodeB review the state/value and send approved flag along with
   signature.(State: value=100, CustomerFlag=**1**)

Can you help me how to add that value while NodeB responding with approve/reject?

Initiator class:

```
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]

        val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)
        val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), iouState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(StateAndContract(iouState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID), txCommand)

        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)
        otherPartyFlow.send(partSignedTx)
        val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
        val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(otherParty)
        otherPartyFlow.send(partSignedTx)
        return partSignedTx
    }
}
```

Acceptor class:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        val receivedData = otherPartyFlow.receive<SignedTransaction>()

        receivedData.unwrap {data -> data }
<<<<< Need help here how to add value and send back >>>>
return updatedData
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to rethink your flow slightly to get this to work. I would say your best bet is rather than sending a signed transaction to the acceptor, send the IOU State itself. The Acceptor class can then alter this flag in the state, and create/sign the transaction. It can then be sent back to the initiator class for it to verify the flag has been changed, sign the transaction and then commit it to the ledger.

```
@Suspendable
override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

    val iouState = IOUState(iouValue, serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), otherParty)

    val otherPartyFlow = initiateFlow(otherParty)
    otherPartyFlow.send(iouState)

    //Receieve back the signedTransaction
    val ptx = otherPartyFlow.receive<SignedTransaction>().unwrap{it}
    val stx = serviceHub.addSignature(ptx)
    //Resolve and commit to the ledger
    subFlow(ResolveTransactionsFlow(stx, otherPartyFlow))
    return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx))
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val receivedData = otherPartyFlow.receive<IOUState>().unwrap{
            //Do any state verification here
            it
        }
        receivedData.customerFlag = 1

       //Create the txn
       val txCommand = Command(IOUContract.Commands.Create(), receivedData.participants.map { it.owningKey })
       val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(StateAndContract(receivedData, IOU_CONTRACT_ID), txCommand)
       //Sign the transaction
       val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
       otherPartyFlow.send(partSignedTx)
       return waitForLedgerCommit(partSignedTx.id)
}
}
```

You could also look into using the signTransactionsFlow for gathering signatures rather than sending back and forth a stx as Ive done above - see https://docs.corda.net/flow-state-machines.html

Comment: Yep - the input list, output list, etc. in the `TransactionBuilder` are protected, and you can't remove elements from them. If you're unwilling to take the approach Raymond suggests, you'd have to make a new `TransactionBuilder` and copy over all the elements in the old `TransactionBuilder`, except the state you want to modify.

Comment: Looks like "sending IOU state instead of signed txn" works for me. Since reassigning the customerFlag in Acceptor class, I have changed customerFlag from val to var (mutable variable) in state object. Wanted to ensure that it is correct approach?

Comment: Since above code is working fine, Can I ask one advise on UI side?
Current Code works like below:
Once entered the details from NodeA, the whole flow will be completed including reassignment of customerFlag (customerFlag=1).
But below is flow that I wanted to develop:
NodeA sends the state to Customer and wait until receive customerFlag value from the Customer Node.
Customer Node will enter the (customerFlag = 1) from Customer Node UI/Shell and then completed the flow. Please advise.

Comment: @OmG I have actually just been solving this in my cordapp and the way I worked around it was to have two seperate flows. So you could have a flow called issue flow which sends the state to the customer with the flag set to 0 (both parties sign the state). Then this state is stored in both vaults. You can then have a activate/setFlag flow which takes in the state with the flag set as 0, and then have an output state with the flag as 1. There may be easier methods to this, but this essentially allows the customer to set the flag from within the UI by simply calling a flow.

Comment: @RaymondMogg I may have some basic(stupid) questions since I am new to Corda? 
Two seperate flow means 2 Initiator(or Issue) class and 2 Acceptor class?
Can I use Finality to store state(set to 0) in both vaults?
How to get output state and set to 1?
How to call activate/SetFlag (2nd) flow from customer UI (I thought each node use same initiator/acceptor flow)?
Can you please share sample code for above flow if you have?
Thanks.

Comment: @OmG no worries at all, I can answer those (might be best in a new question though so I can post some code samples?). Yeah you are right with the first bit, if you have two flows you will have a flow initiated by the client (issuing the state with flag = 0). Once this is finalized you will have another flow initiated by the customer which gets the state and sets its flag to 1. In terms of getting the state, you can create custom flows that query a corda nodes vault and retrieve states with specific filters (i.e get states where flag = 0).

Comment: @RaymondMogg - Bank Node would initiate Issue (Initiator/Acceptor class) flow. This is current flow which I already have. But how Customer node will initiate new Approval (set to 1) flow. All I know that all node(Bank, Customer) initiate only Initiator class and then acceptor class. Can you share some sample code (more specific like NodeA initiate issue flow and NodeB initiate approval flow)?
I have my very first Corda Demo with my Leadership team Tomorrow :) So I am trying to get some basic shape of POC. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have created 2 separate flows client and customer.

1. Client Flow1: 
   Create state with approval flag as 0 and committed to ledger.

   `subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))`
2. Customer Flow2:

   - Extract the state which committed by Client and use that state as input to customer flow.
     `val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED)
     val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<POCState>(criteria)
     val pocState = results.states.last().state.data`
   - Reset the approval flag =1 and commit to ledger.

   `val ourOtherOutputState: POCState = pocState.copy(stateCode = pocStateCode)`

   - Build the transaction and commit to the ledger.

   `val txCommand = Command(BankContract.Commands.Create(), pocState.participants.map { it.owningKey })
           val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(StateAndContract(ourOtherOutputState, POC_CONTRACT_ID), txCommand)
   val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder)
   val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(otherPartyFlow), GATHERING_SIGS.childProgressTracker()))
   return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, FINALISING_TRANSACTION.childProgressTracker()))`

Thank you @Raymond Mogg for your support!